# 知っとった meaning of grammar?

Tags: grammar, translation

What does the grammar form of 知るin the below sentence mean?

闇の世界とは関わるはずがないと知っとったんだろうな

The sentence is from the Japanese version of Harry Potter I

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a contraction of 知っておった which is an archaic/dialectal version of 知っていた, which means "knew".

Comment: This is correct of course, but to add, 居る{おる} (godan) is the archaic/dialectical form of 居る{いる}, the rest follows.